# How come my NSURLSession never starts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsurl, nsurlsession

I have the following code that kicks off a download with NSURLSession, but none of the delegate methods are called:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask1 = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/RARAP1J.jpg"]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask2 = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/JR9ZihS.jpg"]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask3 = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/f4w08VP.jpg"]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask4 = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/MzWvRKa.jpg"]];

    [dataTask1 resume];
    [dataTask2 resume];
    [dataTask3 resume];
    [dataTask4 resume];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"yep");
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"YEAH");
}
```

I don't know why this is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you set the delegates?

Answer (score 0):

My be you did not set delegate for session
try init session with

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
```

Comment: I was under the impression this created a serial queue. I want to make sure that the requests can be executed in parallel.

Comment: if you set delegateQueue is nil. all request will call in other thread. so it executed in parallel

Comment: But the documentation claims it creates a serial queue.

Comment: The serial queue is for the callbacks, @Aloha64 - it has nothing to do with the requests. Read the documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying:

```
[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]]
```

You did not specify a delegate, so how will you get any callbacks? You cannot. You will have to create your data task by calling `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:` so you can add a completion handler.

Of course it would have been better if you had called `sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:` because then you could set yourself as the delegate. But you didn't so obviously those delegate methods will never be called.